# What is the name of the Windows System Menu button?

Tags: windows, windows-7, button

What is the name of the Windows System Menu button?

I am talling about the round glass-orb looking object (on a Windows 7 operating system) that appears in the lower left of the screen -- usually -- that you can click on to see the menu selection of programs on your compter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is called the [Start Button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_menu), and the menu is called the Start Menu. It hasn't changed its name since it was introduced with Windows 95.

Comment: how do you add web links in your answer?

Comment: @VoodooChild: see the formatting hints, on the right side of the screen as you're editing a question or answer. Or go here: [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @VoodooChild There's a Hyperlink button on the edit toolbar (Ctrl+L), or the markdown syntax is defined at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ... but perhaps (I don't know) users need some minimum reputation to be allowed to create hyperlinks.

Comment: The new round button in Vista and 7 was often referred to by MS people as "the pearl" to distinguish it from a button with the word START written on it. I prefer to call it "the marble" because it looks like one. But I agree that "Start button" is the real name.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is called "Start Menu"

Answer (score 0):

"Start Menu" same as it has always been